# nginx load-balancer in front of another nginx?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

I have a working site which looks like.

```
client - nginx - uwsgi - django
```

I'd like to increase the number of the web server and put a load-balancer in front.  (1. to server more user, 2. to prepare machine failure)

Since one of my web server is private hosted, and one is aws hosted, I'm considering nginx as a load-balancer. (aws ELB seems to talk to only ec2 machines)

This is my first time dealing with load-balancer so I'm not sure if I'm after something like..

```
client -- nginx (load-balancer on AWS) 
              \ --- nginx1 - uwsgi1 - django1  (on AWS)
               \
                \--- nginx2 - uwsgi2 - django2  (outside of AWS)
```

Or should I make something like

```
client -- nginx (load-balancer) 
              \ --- uwsgi1 - django1
               \
                \--- uwsgi2 - django2
```

Comment: You may want to consider HAProxy too.

Comment: Hi Instead of using load balancer you can use route53 Routing Policy to serve traffic between on outside of aws and AWS servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any of those two. Doesn't really matter.

Comment: I think keep alive might work better `nginx <-> nginx`.